# web application automation error with input parameter

Tags: automation, blueprism

I am a beginner & trying out automating web applications.

Below is the error I'm getting while passing input to simple mm to inch converter web page .

Internal : Cannot find target element in step 1 of Write Stage 'input' on page 'input'

[image: Error Screenshot]

I expect the spied text box to accept a value

[[image: Spied webpage][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAZN1.png)

attributes screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fskek.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the attributes you’re using to match this element.

Comment: You need to uncheck attributes that are bound to be different from the ones that you obtained after spying. It's never a good idea to spy without editing the attributes as it almost always causes issues sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

The mapping was wrong with the input parameters. It worked after correction